# How can I get the gerrit projects which access have the specific group by gerrit rest api?

Tags: rest, gerrit

How can I get the gerrit projects which have the specific group by gerrit rest api?
I need get all the projects,that these projects access have the specific group?
For example, project A has a read access in reference refs/*, and admin has grant group named xxx read access,then project A has group xxx. My problem is how can I get project A by giving group xxx as parameter through gerrit rest api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command will list all projects on which access rights for xxxxx group are directly assigned. Projects which only inherit access rights for this group are not listed.

```
curl --user USER:PASS --request GET https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/projects/?has-acl-for=xxxxx | sed 1d | jq --raw-output '.[].id'
```

More info in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#list-projects).